# Did "Hitler" declare war on the USA, or did "Germany"?

Tags: discussion

Referring to the question I asked [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/64/why-did-hitler-declare-war-on-the-usa), which word is more correct/consistent?

Comment: What are you saying? I don't understand.

Comment: I'm just wondering whether we should say that Hitler did stuff, or that Germany did stuff. You don't often see other leaders' names used the way Hitler's is. 

For example, not many people write that "Whilhelm II invaded Belgium in WW1", but for some reason many people say that "Hitler invaded Czechoslovakia in WW2". I'm wondering whether we should only say "Hitler" when referring to the actual person, and not in place of the country he led.

Comment: Possibly asking when a nation is referred too, should it be the nation, or the leader of the nation that is referred too?

Comment: I agree with canadiancreed. The Nazis would work best, though. also, questions like this would be better in the chat.

Comment: Adolf Hitler was the official head of the German state when Germany and the USA respectively declared war. Thus, Germany as a nation also declared war. Simple, no?

Comment: Meta is for discussion about the site, this would be a Question **for** the site

Comment: At times, meta can be used to ask about a question (to clarify scope, administrative issues, etc), but this post is *so* specific to that question, comments (in that question) would be a better place to address your wording.

Comment: vote to reopen: i don't think the poster is looking for a history answer - i think he is asking about how to phrase this type of question in general on the site